# How to diagnose Google App Engine Flask Memory Leak

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I have a Google App Engine app running (Flask app) that seems to have a memory leak. See the plot of the memory usage below. The memory usage continually creeps up until it hits the limit and the instance is shutdown and a new one is started up.

It's a simple API with about 8 endpoints. None of them handle large amounts of data.

I added an endpoint that takes a memory snapshot with the tracemalloc package, and compares it to the last snapshot and then writes the output to Google Cloud Storage.

I don't see anything in the reports that indicates a memory leak. The peak memory usage is recorded as about 0.12 GiB.

I am also calling gc.collect() at the end of every function that is called by each endpoint.

Any ideas on how to diagnose this, or what might be causing it?

[image]

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions here, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439727/python-google-app-engine-can-not-release-memory-of-object-array).  Unfortunately, I've never seen a good answer.  It seems that memory should be recycled more quickly.

Comment: @BrainPermafrost - have you been able to solve this, please? If yes, I would appreciate any info on how.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the exact same problem. It was happening so often on my F1 instance that I finally upgraded to F2... Within 24 hours it's happened again at the higher 768 MiB threshold. It's extremely frustrating. 

If anyone has found a solution, please point me in the right direction. Even advice on how to recycle memory more often.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons for this situation to be encountered. Is your app creating temporary files? Temporary files can be a cause of a memory leak. Temporary files can also be created from errors, or warnings. First of all, I would check my Stackdriver logs for errors and warnings and I would try to fix them.

Is your application interacting with databases or storage buckets ? Some memory related issues can be related to a bad interaction of your app with any data storage service. This issue was also encountered [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1253) and was mitigated by treating the Google Cloud Storage errors.

Another thing that you can do is investigate a bit the way of the memory is used in your function. For this you have some nice tools you can use like [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) and [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy). Playing with those tools may give you valuable clues about what your issue is.

Comment: Thank you, super helpful.  We are getting a lot of error messages. We will start there.